# Updating a string through iteration in C++

Tags: c++, windows

OK, so I'm trying to make a string thing, so that the string is updated. Sort of like you have a string "hello" and I want it to update itself somewhat like "h" "he" "hel" "hell" "hello"

So, I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("title game");
    system("color 0a");
    string sentence = "super string ";

    for(int i=1; i<sentence.size(); i++){
        cout << sentence.substr(0, i) <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code returns out like:

"s
"su"
"sup"
"supe"
"super"

Obviously on different lines, but when I remove the end line, the sentence builder just goes berserk. It displays something like "spupsppuepr sttrrtrsubstringsubstring"

Is there anyway I can update the string on THE SAME LINE? (and not have it completely destroyed)

Comment: "goes beserk" is an exaggeration; it prints exactly the same thing, just without the line breaks.

Comment: Just so you know, `conio` is deprecated and the `system`s can be replaced with `SetConsoleTitle` and `SetConsoleTextAttribute` respectively. While I'm at it, `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h` should be `cstdio` and `cstdlib`, and `using namespace std` statements, especially global ones, are bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could print a carriage return character `'\r'` at each iteration, returning the cursor to the beginning of the line:

```
for(int i=1; i<sentence.size(); i++){
    cout << '\r' << sentence.substr(0, i);
}
```

Or just output each character in sequence:

```
for(int i=0; i<sentence.size(); i++){
    cout << sentence[i];
}
```

You probably also want to insert a short delay for each loop iteration to achieve a typewriter effect.

Answer (score 0):

Running your code produces this:

./a.out
ssusupsupesupersuper super ssuper stsuper strsuper strisuper strinsuper string

This is exactly what you tell it to do. It's the same as with the endl but without the newlines. If you don't want it to repeat all the letters, you need to iterate through the string itself, not through the substrings.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("title game");
    system("color 0a");
    string sentence = "super string ";

    for(int i=0; i<sentence.size(); i++){
        cout << sentence[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice: use `While loop`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    system("title game");
    system("color 0a");
    char* sentence = "super string";

    while( *sentence ) std::cout <<  *sentence++;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This really isn't the same bit of code at all. This uses a `char*` and not a `std::string`. Also, using `(*sentence++)` is pretty insane unless you know exactly what you're doing.